Drifting local time vs server time synchronization
Imagine a server sending you (the client) game snapshots each 30ms.
Your interpolation time is set at around 100ms, so ideally you are interpolating between 4th and 3rd snapshot, so by the time you are done with the 3rd, rolling over to 2nd, there is a new snapshot in the queue. If all things are stable, you will keep using always queue indexes 3,2, and sometimes 1.
To properly align your render to this 100ms delay you have already computed a compensation factor based around median RTT/2 to convert between server time and local time.
Now, the question: what if there is a drift in either local time or server time, cause the clocks are not ideal and are actually running a bit differently. A key factor here is not that they are different, but they drift.
This means, over time your client time will slip into deeper past (for example), and now you are interpolating between, say, 6th and 5th snapshot in the queue. Now it a matter of time before you reach end of the queue and desync entirely.
How to prevent this?
Doing constant pings and recalculations of both RTT and (server local time - client local time) is unstable, because client local time in absence of high  res timers is actually just a \$ \sum dt\$ , aka a running accumulator of frame delta times. For game pauses or hardware lags the frame time sometimes can jump abruptly, causing chaos with client local time to render time calculation. Using system clock for local time doesn't solve the issue of a drift too, as it can be present too.

I've concluded there is no need to "deliver time slices" (from the server) if the client does the polling; and the server simply responds. The client sends commands (command codes and target points); the server reponds with an "OK" not OK and runs its own simulation in parallel with the client (the "animation"); the moves are all deterministic. A collision on the server is a "charge" or "obstacle" or "Friend" event on the client (obtained at the start of a frame; for proper timing) and the client is directed to attack; animate around the object; etc. More SCADA than client server.

"Dropped connections" are obviously clients that are no longer "polling". A minimum polling usually involves asking "is there anything I should do?" e.g. Run; find cover; recover; fire on point A; etc. Polling stops also when the client is "killed".
